# OpenCV resize an image to (28,28)

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to run a code but I keep getting this error code.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

the line the error is referring to is this. I've tried looking it up before but none of the solutions fit my problem

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
```

Comment: make sure you have data on image variable.

Answer (score 0):

seems the image your read is not properly read or your image may be corrupt, please check the image shape before resize the image